# Daemonizing an eventmachine app

Tags: ruby, daemon, eventmachine

I have an event-machine based app that I want to run as a daemon, so I can easily start stop it.

I'm attempting to use the daemons gem, however it appears to just skip over the EM runloop and dies at the end of the script.

An example:

```
require 'daemons'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'logging'

logger = Logging.logger['DAEMON']
logger.level = :debug

logger.add_appenders \
  Logging.appenders.file('logs/daemon.log')

Daemons.daemonize
File.open('/tmp/mydaemon.pid', 'w') { |f| f.puts(Process.pid) }

EM.run {
  EM.add_periodic_timer(1) { logger.info "I'm logging in a daemon" }
}
```

I've also tried doing it in Daemon.run or Process.daemon, with no better luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Does execution stop after the call to daemonize or later?

Comment: After. It detaches from the terminal, creates the pid file, and then nothing else happens. Nothing ever appears in the log (If I disable daemonizing, the log receives input)

Comment: I took the code from the example provided in the gem and made [this](https://gist.github.com/sid-code/8ddb4573ea683bf6bec9). and it works fine. Does this isolate the problem to the logger?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu (or another Upstart-based Linux), I have used the following script and service configuration to run EventMachine services. Maybe it will work for you. For other init based systems you can probably modify the approach.

In this example, *SVC* is the name of my app, and *BASEHOME* is the location I installed it to (`/usr/share` in my case)

**Create an init control script for your EM server**

Place this file in the lib directory of your EM app, and update *SVC* and *BASEDIR* appropriately.

```
#!/bin/bash
SVC=em-server
BASEHOME=/usr/share    
BASEDIR=$BASEHOME/$SVC    
echo Starting $SVC: `date`
echo Running as: `whoami`   
echo Running in: $BASEDIR
### Set RVM source if you are using it, otherwise remove these two lines
source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm use 2.1
###
cd $BASEDIR    
ruby $BASEDIR/lib/em_server.rb
```

**Configure Upstart to run the control script**

```
sudo -i

SVC=em-server
BASEDIR=/usr/share/$SVC

adduser $SVC --system
usermod -a  -G em-service $SVC
chown --recursive $SVC:$SVCGRP $BASEDIR
chmod --recursive 660 $BASEDIR
chmod 550 $BASEDIR/lib/start_em_service_upstart.sh
chmod 550 $BASEDIR/scripts/*
cat > /etc/init/$SVC.conf <<EOF
    description     "EM Server"
    start on (starting network-interface
     or starting network-manager
     or starting networking)
    stop on runlevel [!2345]
    setuid $SVC
    exec $BASEDIR/lib/start_em_service_upstart.sh
    respawn
EOF

initctl reload-configuration

exit
```

Run `sudo service em-server start` to try it out.

Be sure to check `/var/log/upstart/em_server.log` for feedback on whether the service starts as expected or other issues occur.

Also, note that RVM can cause all kinds of issues. In my example I set it up as multiuser to avoid annoying Ruby and Bundler issuers. Probably not ideal though